# How to use a SQL table instead of a long string for a WHERE in (string) condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select customer_id, prod_id, prod_start, prod_price
from prod_table
where prod_id in (PRODLIST)
```

Unfortunately, `PRODLIST` contains about 68K 6-digit numbers. When I try to run this query on my server, I get an error that SQL can't handle so many `prod_id` as presented in a string.

My next thought was to put all the 68K 6-digit numbers into a single column table `included_prodlist` with column heading `included_prod_id`. The resulting `included_prodlist` table would then be a single column table with 68K rows, and each column would be a unique 6-digit number.

I could then do an `inner join` of the original query with `included_prodlist` as follows:

```
select customer_id, prod_id, prod_start, prod_price
from prod_table
where prod_id in (select included_prod_id from included_prodlist)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working i.e. the query returns no entries.

1. Is this the proper way to deal with long conditions?
2. Should I be using an `inner join` instead?

   ```
   select customer_id, prod_id, prod_start, prod_price
   from prod_table
   inner join included_prodlist on prod_table.prod_id = included_prodlist.included_prod_id
   ```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  And please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean in detail?

Comment: The query looks fine. `where prod_id in (select included_prod_id from included_prodlist)` should do what you want. Are you sure the `included_prodlist` is filled with data? Did you commit your inserts? And no, `IN` is perfect for this. Don't join.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten. I think my issue was the formatting of `included_prodlist` it seems to be working now. Most appreciated!

Comment: I see. You should consider creating a foreign key, so `included_prodlist.included_prod_id` can only reference existing `prod_table.prod_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the values in to a table is highly recommended.  The one column should be the primary key.

Then, I would go for `exists` rather than `not in`:

```
select p.customer_id, p.prod_id, p.prod_start, p.prod_price
from prod_table p
where exists (select 1
              from included_prodlist ip
              where ip.included_prod_id = p.prod_id
             );
```

Comment: Thank you, so `not exists` would actually return a row where the `prod_id` matches the `included_prod_id`? And why `select 1`?  Will this still allow the query to return multiple matches?

Comment: @user50710 . . . I misread the query; I thought there was a `not in`.  Hmm, you can try this.  But it probably won't work either.  The issue is probably the comparison of the values -- something like extra spaces in a string or a type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Of course using `INNER JOIN` can be more helpful with a better performance. For best practices create the index which is recommended in query execution plan :)

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN on a single column table is preferable on a nested query

In a nested query the internal query runs 1st and its results are placed in the outer query

Using join, there is only one query, preferably on indexed columns

You will be able to see the differences adding EXPLAIN before the SELECT command

I would generate the product list table as a temp table, with an indexed column, that way the query would run with join even faster